# Unable to connect to my Ubuntu machine using Putty remotely?

Tags: networking, ssh, sshd

I am new to Ubuntu, I have it installed on my computer (not on a virtual machine) and I am trying to connect to my Ubuntu machine remotely through PuTTY. I am getting the IP address of the Ubuntu machine using `ifconfig`. I'm trying to connect to this IP address with PuTTY but I am getting the following error message:

```
Network Error: Connection Timed Out
```

As shown below:

[image: Image showing "Network Error: Connection Timed Out" message from PuTTY]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You ubuntu system works fine, you should check your firewall settings from your local pc or maybe you have a firewall device at your lan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, AFAIR correctly you need the openssh server for that which is NOT installed by default.

So try

```
aptitude install openssh-server
```

and try again.

So when the openssh-server is installed, try to see if it is running and to which port it listens to.

E.G.

```
[simmel]@[mars]$ service ssh status
ssh start/running, process 1279
```

so mine is running, let's see to which ip(s) it listens to.

```
[simmel]@[mars]$ sudo netstat -tlpn
Aktive Internetverbindungen (Nur Server)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1279/sshd
```

So it's running and listening on all interfaces, which is the way it's setup by default.

Now try to connect to the server from localhost, does this work?

```
[simmel]@[mars]$ ssh -p22 simmel@localhost
Enter passphrase for key '/home/simmel/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

It's working too. So the service itself is up an running and waiting for connections.

Now go to the system from where you would like to connect and install nmap and then scan the system, you should see the open ports after the scan.

```
sudo aptitude install nmap
```

and then (as root)

```
nmap -sS 10.128.225.177

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-04-01 14:33 CEST
Nmap scan report for 10.128.225.177
Host is up (0.00075s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 8.45 seconds
```

Alternatevly you could try

```
telnet <ip-adress> 22
```

If both don't work your system def. blocks these request, possibly as suggested with a firewall. Most common is iptables. So give it a try and check on the system you installed the openssh-server

```
iptables -L
```

If it looks different like this

```
[simmel]@[mars]$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

an active iptables might be blocking these requests.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I wrote that command in terminal. As a response I got: "No packages will be installed, upgraded or removed. 0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 488 not upgraded. Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used." By the way using apt-get instal openssh-server I have installed it. But it is not working yet.

Comment: i updated my answer so you can try to narrow down the problem

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I have tried and it worked. Thank you again.